# Iterate through DataTable

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to prove equality between two datables, albeit the values in my second table are 1.5* the values in the first.

I'm unable to iterate over more than the first rows of my datatables when performing the comparison. The foreach loop iterates over the first row only.

My comparison function:

```
public static bool CompareRowContent(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
            foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
            {
                var decimals1 = GetDecimals(row1.ItemArray, (decimal)1.5);
                var decimals2 = GetDecimals(row2.ItemArray, (decimal)1.0);
                if (decimals1.SequenceEqual(decimals2))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

The multiplier function:

```
static List<decimal> GetDecimals(object[] array, decimal multiplier)
        {
            var list = new List<decimal>();
            foreach (object value in array)
            {
                try
                {
                    decimal result = (decimal) value;
                    result *= multiplier;
                    list.Add(result);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Error.
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
```

...and the test in which I am trying to prove that the rows are equal:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Compare_Values()
        {
            bool compareValueResult = Helper.CompareRowContent(_table1, _table2);
            Assert.IsTrue(compareValueResult, "Row content does not match");
        }
```

I expect the foreach loop to iterate through each row in the table and return true if matched, false if not. The actual result is 'true' based on the first line only - but the other rows are not evaluated.

If I watch the decimals1 and decimals2 variables, the whole table is there...but never used in the loop.

Please help me loop over my whole datatable!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Trust me, the things that your debugger could tell you about your code are pretty astonishing.

Comment: Your are `return`ing for both true and false case so it will never get passed the first row. You want a single result, or a result for each row?

Comment: I see re: the return statements. I'm trying to compare each item in both tables, but return false as soon as there's a mismatch.

Comment: Your `return` after `if (decimals1.SequenceEqual(decimals2))` is premature. You shouldn't return, rather, store the comparison somewhere and return only after you iterate over both tables.

Comment: Then only return on false, never on true.

Comment: Also be careful that your sort order in both tables are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all. See where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a nested loop that will compare every row in table1 against every row in table2.

The simplest way to write that code is something like:

```
public static bool CompareRowContent(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
{
    if (table1.Rows.Count != table2.Rows.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row1 = table1.Rows[i];
        var row2 = table2.Rows[i];
        var decimals1 = GetDecimals(row1.ItemArray, (decimal)1.5);
        var decimals2 = GetDecimals(row2.ItemArray, (decimal)1.0);
        if (!decimals1.SequenceEqual(decimals2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @user29353 and/or pick for a matching primary key value